# JAVA how to add an output from a method

Tags: java, file-upload

I am trying to only stringbuild for "successful" ones. My success is in FileUpload, i tried doing FileUpload loopLocation.getSuccess but that did not work. How do I get the success from the FileUpload method to only stirng build in this case:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (FileUpload loopLocation : uploadList){
            logger.debug("string builder time");
            sb.append(loopLocation.getFilename());
            sb.append(": ");
            sb.append("<br />");
            sb.append("<br />");
            sb.append("<a href =");
            sb.append(loopLocation.getLocation());
            sb.append("/");
            sb.append(number);
            sb.append("/");
            sb.append(loopLocation.getFilename());
            sb.append(">");
            sb.append(loopLocation.getLocation());
            sb.append("/");
            sb.append(number);
            sb.append("/");
            sb.append(loopLocation.getFilename());
            sb.append("</a>");
            sb.append("<br />");
            sb.append("<br />");
            logger.debug(sb.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the source code for  `FileUpload`?

Comment: What is the return type of the getSuccess() method? Could you share the FileUpload class or at least this method?

Answer (score 1):

Added this around inside my for loop and that works

```
            if (loopLocation.getSuccess()){   //only builds successful ones

}
```